# check if element is repeated in list in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
multi_available(X):-
   member(X,
      [grilled_chicken,
         jambo_beef,
       grilled_cheese_sandwich,roast_beef,potato_salad,chicken_rice,
         jambo_beef,
         service_dish,service_dish,
       beef_stew,potato_corn,grilled_chicken,roast_beef,mushroom_rice,
         service_dish,
         jambo_beef]).

member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]):-member(X,T).
```

How can I check if an element is repeated in a list in Prolog?

Comment: 1. Don't link to external material whenever possible; especially to images. 2. What have you tried already?

Comment: i have tried to add X to a list whenever i found it , then i checked if there where more than one item but it did not work i used add_list([], L, L).
add_list([H|T], L, L1) :-add(H, L2, L1), add_list(T, L, L2). here multi_available(X):-member(X,[grilled_chicken,jambo_beef,grilled_cheese_sandwich,roast_beef,potato_salad,chicken_rice,jambo_beef,service_dish,service_dish,beef_stew,potato_corn,grilled_chicken,roast_beef,mushroom_rice,service_dish,jambo_beef]),add_list([_], Y, L1), X is L1.

Comment: Why not avoid adding `X` to the list if it is already a member, then you won't have to check for duplicates later?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Prologue of Prolog](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue):

> **member(X, L)** is true if X is an element of the list L.
>   **select(X, Xs, Ys)** is true if X is an element of the
>   list Xs and Ys  is the list Xs with one occurrence of X removed.

I get the following simple solution:

```
:- use_module(library(basic/lists)).
multi_available(L, X) :- select(X, L, R), member(X, R).
```

It might not be the most efficient. But it works:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 2, Runtime Library 1.2.5
(c) 1985-2017, XLOG Technologies GmbH, Switzerland
?- multi_available([a,b,c,b,a,d],X).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = b ;
X = a ;
No
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you just want to know whether an element occurs more than once or whether you need how many times it occurs, so here's both!

See if the List contains Element, +1 to Count for every occurrence

```
occurrences(Element,[Head|Tail], Count, OutputCount) :-
    Element = Head,
    NewCount is Count + 1,
    occurrences(Element, Tail, NewCount, OutputCount).
```

Element does not match the first element of the List? Don't add 1, go to the next element.

```
occurrences(Element, [Head|Tail], Count, OutputCount) :-
    Element \= Head,
    occurrences(Element, Tail, Count, OutputCount).
```

If the List is empty, return the final count

```
occurrences(Element,[],Count,Count).
```

Since the Count can't be negative, just pass it on as Zero and only return the result.

```
occurrences(Element, List, Count) :- occurrences(Element, List, 0, Count).
```

Check whether the result is higher than 1

```
moreThanOnce(Element, List) :-
    occurrences(Element, List, Count),
    Count > 1.
```

Does Element occur more than once in List?

```
?- moreThanOnce(1, [1,2,3,1,1,1]).
```

How many times does it occur?

```
?- occurrences(1, [1,2,3,1,1,1], Count).
```

Note that if a list is empty, [Head|Tail] will automatically fail and List = [] automatically succeeds. This means that OutputCount remains empty throughout the program, UNTIL the end condition is met, which is only reached after [Head|Tail] fails, meaning the list is empty. I hope this is clear enough, be sure to ask for clarifications if it isn't.